# make: *** No rule to make target `all'. Stop. Eclipse error

Tags: windows, eclipse, makefile, eclipse-cdt

I've just downloaded Eclipse CDT developer kit (87MB) for Windows. I've also installed MinGW, and msys. 
  I also added this to PATH: C:\msys\1.0\bin;C:\mingw\bin. and restarted computer after that. I've checked by type "make --version" in cmd and it works.

However, for some reason I cannot compile my C project. I don't get binary files and got only the following things in COnsole:

```
**** Build of configuration Default for project XXX ****

make all 
make: *** No rule to make target `all'.  Stop.
```

Could some one help me with this please?

Comment: I have same Error can you tell me how to solve this Error.

Comment: @SamadhanMedge The last answer at the bottom was how I fixed it. To be honest, I can't recall any details better than that. Hope you have found a way to solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you for reply and I solve the error by twokats answer

Comment: @chepukha If one of the answers was how you fixed it; seems like it would be good to mark it as your accepted answer. :D

Answer (score 13):

For future reference, if you're trying to import an existing project with a makefile...

This message will still pop up if your makefile doesn't have an "all" rule. Using the "Generate Makefiles automatically" option should take care of this automatically. If you don't want makefiles made for you, you have at least 3 simple options...

**Option 1**

If you *don't want* to use a rule by that name, use [twokats' solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3730704/1519716). Here's a clarification.

1. Go to Project Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Behaviour Tab.
2. Leave Build (Incremental Build) Checked.
3. Remove "all" from the text box next to Build (Incremental Build).

This lets Eclipse know you aren't trying to use a make target called "all". For some reason, that is the default.

**Option 2**

Use something similar to [Etienne Racine's makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4347655/1519716). Note, the `all:    $(TARGET)` line is the rule that Eclipse is complaining it can't find.

**Option 3**

Substitute "all" with a rule name of your choice, and be sure to include that rule in your makefile.

Answer (score 6):

Just for your reference, there is a way to configure the CDT build options.  I had this same error message (although I **did** have a make target - just not named "all") and found this solution (for Galileo + CDT):

Right click your project and choose **Properties**.  The Properties dialog will appear and you should see a **C/C++ Build** option where you can set specific build options.  Highlight this item, and the Properties page will appear.  Choose the configuration you wish to modify, and then in the section below that you should see 2 tabs:  **Builder Settings** and  **Behavior**.  It is the **Behavior** tab you want.  In this section you can set preferences for build settings and workbench settings, including specifying a target name (default is "all") or turning off automatic builds.

This was incredibly helpful to me when I started using the CDT.  My source code is separate from the build area, and until I configure, no makefiles exist.  When I configured, my default target name is explicitly "default", not "all".  It was annoying to have Eclipse report an error in my project before I did anything.  Setting up the environment to match my development worked wonders.  HTH.

Answer (score 5):

right click the project Properties->C/C++ Build, in the "Builder Settings" check the "Generate Makefiles automatically" option, and then select the "Builder type" option to "Internal builder", and then click ok, the problem was solved!

Comment: What if the whole “make file generation” is grayed out?

Answer (score 2):

I spent a lot of time on this error and now realized that those projects that are not compiled were created before I installed MinGW and msys so there was no makefile before. And there was no include folder with link to the makefile. That's the reason why I could not compile it. Now as I create new project, it's fine.

However, I wonder if there is any way to add the path to makefile for the previous projects?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, yeah personally I always install MinGW before CDT (or other IDEs) so that they can configure themselves (i.e. auto-finding MinGW) when they get installed.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at your makefile (or create one if missing). That's the default makefile :

```
CXXFLAGS =  -O2 -g -Wall -fmessage-length=0
OBJS =      main.cpp
LIBS =
TARGET =      main.exe

$(TARGET):  $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJS) $(LIBS)
all:    $(TARGET)
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(TARGET)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've fixed it but don't remember now how exactly it was fixed