# Eclipse Juno CDT Error: No rule to make target `all'

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos

I just installed `Eclipse Juno` and am trying to make a simple `Hello World` C++ Project. I also have `autoconf` installed, however I get the error:

> Error 127 occurred while running autoreconf.

I have already read [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574187/eclipse-cdt-no-rule-to-make-target-all)  about a similar problem, but none of the suggestions seemed to solve the problem.

How do I get rid of these errors? The project was a `Hello world C++ Autotools Project` if that helps.

Comment: click on the project in explorer and select build this

Comment: I get another error, "No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

possibly you have created an Autotools project. You have to create an Executable Project.

http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Fgetting_started%2Fcdt_w_basic.htm

check properties.

Comment: What is the difference between an Autotools project and an executable project? Are there advantages of using one over the other? Also, I still get the "No rule to make target all" error even when my project explorer is empty.

Comment: look at Project Type. From the Project type list, expand Executable and select Hello World C++ Project. when your project explorer is empty this is not strange at all. follow this tutorial, click what has to be clicked and give here a feedback. Have you created a new project?

Comment: the error is on Run command, right? so now you can at least Build the project, right?

Comment: Right, there are no errors regarding the executable project itself.

Comment: now your problem is that you cannot Run the project. You must ensure in Properties that path to your executable binary is specified or alternatively you can run it from the command line ./path_to_executable/name_of_executable

Comment: Right, so now it says that there are errors existing in the project, but I can run it and it prints out "Hello World" to the console.

Comment: what errors, and what it means "it says" ? please be specific if you want me to help

Comment: Under the problems tab, the errors that I have already mentioned are still there. However, I am able to run the project, though I still want to know how to get rid of the errors.

Comment: I can also tell you that I tested this out with two projects. One uses the Mac OSX toolchain, doesn't cause any errors, but raises the "No binary found" error when run. The other uses the Cross GCC toolchain, causes errors before being run, but can actually be run.

Comment: Oh wait, never mind, the reason it raised the no binary found error was because it wasn't built. I assumed it automatically builded for the Mac OSX toolchain project.