# Eclipse on Ubuntu: No rule to make target `all' error using existing makefile/project

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt, makefile

I'm running Eclipse 3.7.2 with CDT installed. Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

I have an existing makefile C++ project that I'm trying to import from Geany. I can run `$ make` in the project's root directory, and everything builds as expected.

**My error** in Eclipse:

> make: *** No rule to make target `all'. Stop.

**My question**: how do I eliminate this error?

Here are the exact steps I'm taking:

1. File>New>Makefile project with existing code.

   - Existing Code Location set to project's root directory.
   - Languages set to C++
   - Toolchain set to Cross GCC
2. In Project Properties>C/C++ Build...

   - In Builder Settings...

     - Using default build command
     - NOT using generate makefiles automatically (is unavailable)
   - In Behaviour...

     - Using Build (Incremental build) << all
     - Using Clean << clean

[Eclipse CDT: no rule to make target all](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12574187/1519716) comes close to answering the problem I'm trying to correct, but I have the same issue as OP: generate makefile automatically is unavailable.

I've tried [make: *** No rule to make target `all'. Stop. Eclipse error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3714852/1519716)'s top rated solution as well. However, when I uncheck the Build (Incremental Build) option, then build does absolutely nothing, so this isn't right either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just figured out the solution. As usual, it should have been obvious.

[make: *** No rule to make target `all'. Stop. Eclipse error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3714852/1519716)'s top rated answer was right on track, but slightly vague. Here's the solution:

1. Go to Project Properties > C/C++ Build > Behaviour tab...
2. **Leave Build (Incremental Build) enabled**
3. Remove "all" from the text box.

The error was being thrown because Eclipse was trying to find a rule to build "all", which was specified as a target by default.

Removing "all" (and leaving everything else as default) tells Eclipse to build the project in the exact same manner that calling `$ make` from the terminal would.

If I'm wildly incorrect in any of these statements, feel free to correct me.